# Rolling max value with groupby on multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe on which I want to compute maximum of rolling previous 3 month's value.
Below is the dataframe:

```
VIN   Year_Month    Amount  
  V1    2012-01      196     
  V2    2012-01      113     
  V3    2012-01      177     
  V1    2012-02      154     
  V2    2012-02      129     
  V4    2012-02      156     
  V2    2012-03      100     
  V3    2012-03      174     
  V4    2012-03      127     
  V1    2012-04      139    
  V3    2012-04      194     
  V4    2012-04      178
```

Using the following piece of code I am trying to compute the **max value for each VIN in last 3 month**

```
df['Max_3M_Value'] = df.groupby(['VIN','Year_Month'])['Amount'].rolling(3).max().fillna(0)
```

But the above code is giving error:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

The resultant dataframe I am looking is :

```
  VIN  Year_Month   Amount  Max_3M_Value
   V1   2012-01      196     196
   V2   2012-01      113     129
   V3   2012-01      177     194
   V1   2012-02      154     196
   V2   2012-02      129     129
   V4   2012-02      156     178
   V2   2012-03      100     129
   V3   2012-03      174     194
   V4   2012-03      127     178
   V1   2012-04      139     196
   V3   2012-04      194     194
   V4   2012-04      178     178
```

I have to compute the max value using `rolling` only .I know we can solve this using `pd.pivot_table()`, but that is not needed.

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the error by using only the returned values, but you have to make sure that the order of the rows does not change during the operation:

```
df['Max_3M_Value'] = df.groupby(['VIN','Year_Month'])['Amount'].rolling(3).max().fillna(0).values
```

In your given example, your groups are too small (1 element each) to be able to apply a rolling with a window of 3:

```
>>> df.groupby(['VIN','Year_Month'])['Amount'].count()

VIN  Year_Month
V1   2012-01       1
     2012-02       1
     2012-04       1
V2   2012-01       1
     2012-02       1
     2012-03       1
V3   2012-01       1
     2012-03       1
     2012-04       1
V4   2012-02       1
     2012-03       1
     2012-04       1
```

I believe, what you really want is to group only by 'VIN':

```
df['Max_3M_Value'] = df.groupby('VIN')['Amount'].transform(lambda s: s.rolling(3, min_periods=1).max())
```

output:

```
   VIN Year_Month  Amount  Max_3M_Value
0   V1    2012-01     196           196
1   V2    2012-01     113           113
2   V3    2012-01     177           177
3   V1    2012-02     154           196
4   V2    2012-02     129           129
5   V4    2012-02     156           156
6   V2    2012-03     100           129
7   V3    2012-03     174           177
8   V4    2012-03     127           156
9   V1    2012-04     139           196
10  V3    2012-04     194           194
11  V4    2012-04     178           178
```

output for a rolling window of 2:

```
   VIN Year_Month  Amount  Max_3M_Value
0   V1    2012-01     196           196
1   V2    2012-01     113           113
2   V3    2012-01     177           177
3   V1    2012-02     154           196
4   V2    2012-02     129           129
5   V4    2012-02     156           156
6   V2    2012-03     100           129
7   V3    2012-03     174           177
8   V4    2012-03     127           156
9   V1    2012-04     139           154
10  V3    2012-04     194           194
11  V4    2012-04     178           178
```

If really what you want is a simple max per group, you can just do:

```
>>> df['Max_3M_Value'] = df.groupby('VIN')['Amount'].transform('max')
>>> df
   VIN Year_Month  Amount  Max_3M_Value
0   V1    2012-01     196           196
1   V2    2012-01     113           129
2   V3    2012-01     177           194
3   V1    2012-02     154           196
4   V2    2012-02     129           129
5   V4    2012-02     156           178
6   V2    2012-03     100           129
7   V3    2012-03     174           194
8   V4    2012-03     127           178
9   V1    2012-04     139           196
10  V3    2012-04     194           194
11  V4    2012-04     178           178
```

Comment: Nice explanation. +1

Comment: @mozway: What if we use `rolling(2,min_periods=1)`? Still your code will work? BTW, I am getting `V1`,`V2` etc in Max_3M_Value.

Comment: I replaced my answer with an alternative that should work in any case. Let me know…

Comment: @mozway. Your output is not what the OP expects.

Comment: @Corralien I think the output of OP is incorrect. What the current output describes is a simple max per group (*not* a rolling max), which presents no challenge. I'm adding this possibility to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> df['Max_3M_Value'] = df.groupby('VIN')['Amount'] \
                           .rolling(3).max().bfill().astype(int) \
                           .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

```
>>> df
   VIN Year_Month  Amount  Max_3M_Value
0   V1    2012-01     196           196
1   V2    2012-01     113           129
2   V3    2012-01     177           194
3   V1    2012-02     154           196
4   V2    2012-02     129           129
5   V4    2012-02     156           178
6   V2    2012-03     100           129
7   V3    2012-03     174           194
8   V4    2012-03     127           178
9   V1    2012-04     139           196
10  V3    2012-04     194           194
11  V4    2012-04     178           178
```

Comment: It won't work if you try to assign again to original df (NB. I didn't downvote)

Comment: @pythondumb, I updated my answer. Can you check it's what you expect, please?